# OpenId Connect User Not Logged Out When Using IP Address in End Session URI (discovery document end_session_endpoint) . Using Gluu identity server

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid-connect, gluu

When I click logout in a .Net client application I am successfully logged out if the end session end point ("end_session_endpoint" in the discovery document) uses the domain name. For example, the framework redirects to the identity server (Gluu) with the below url and it logs out the application perfectly.

```
https://my-gluu-server.com/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/end_session?
post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2Fsignout-callback-oidc
&id_token_hint=<MY JWT...>
&state=CfDJ8AjASIR7C_....
&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0
&x-client-ver=5.5.0.00
```

But when I change it to use the IP address (because the domain name is not resolvable where we intend to host it) it fails to logout. When I click a private page it goes back to the Gluu server and no login is required (because I am not logged out), it then redirects me back to the .Net client application.

```
https://10.10.10.10/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/end_session?
post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2Fsignout-callback-oidc
&id_token_hint=<MY JWT...>
&state=CfDJ8AjASIR7C_....
&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0
&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
```

Is Gluu or the OIDC flow checking the url (issuer?) and if so is there a way to work around this, so that both the IP address and domain name can be recognised as valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use HTTPS against an IP-address:

```
https://10.10.10.10
```

You must always use a domain when you use HTTPS, otherwise you have to use HTTP.  But using HTTP will give you other problems, especially with the cookies that the browser will reject. So, get a domain for 10.10.10.10 that the client will trust.